How to make a SIMPLE build of VSCode - Open Source
I want to build VSCode from source. I've forked the repo and got it on my desktop. Now I want to build VSCode and run it with the MINIMAL requirements. I don't need an executable and I only need it for Windows. Basically, what I want is a customizable Code - OSS window.
